# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is of class $C^1$, show that $f$ does not carry $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is of class $C^1$, show that $f$ does not carry $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. In few words I have to show that $f(\mathbb{R})$ contains no open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Sard's theorem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem)

Comment: Can you outline a sketch of the proof using it?

Comment: I have never read it in my book, so I think there must be another way to prove it

Comment: In that case, could you please say something about where the question arises (the subject and level of the course, the textbook, what relevant results you've seen)? Thanks. :)

Comment: Textbook: Analysis on Manifolds, by J.Munkres; I've just studied diffeomorphisms and in particular the following result: let $A$ be open in $\mathbf{R}^n$; let $g:A\to\mathbf{R}^n$ be a function of class $C^1$. If the subset $E$ of $A$ has measure zero in $\mathbf{R}^n$, then the set $g(E)$ also has measure zero in $\mathbf{R}^n$. I think this theorem may turn out to be useful, however in my case $g$ isn't of the form  $g:A\to\mathbf{R}^n$, where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$

Comment: I'm gonna prove that $f(\mathbf{R})$ has measure zero in  $\mathbf{R}^2$

Comment: If you embed $\mathbf{R}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ in "the obvious way", you can apply the theorem you cite.

Comment: I'm not sure about doing this thing, that is the problem

Comment: Which is the "obvious way"?

Answer (score 2):

Just to flesh out [the answer given in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305530/if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2-is-of-class-c1-show-that-f-does-not-carry#comment2651460_1305530):

Let $f:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}^2$ be your given function. Define $g:\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ by the function
$$ g(x,y) = f(x) $$

1. Clearly $g$ is $C^1$.
2. The set $E = \{(x,0)|x\in\mathbf{R}\}$ (the $x$-axis) is a measure zero subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$.
3. So by [your quoted theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305530/if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2-is-of-class-c1-show-that-f-does-not-carry#comment2651453_1305530) $g(E)$ has measure zero.
4. But $g(E) = f(\mathbb{R})$ by construction.